# Uploading binary file to SQL Server via Rails Carrierwave

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I would like to use gems like carrierwave or paperclip but I am having a hard time understanding how this is possible with my issue.

I have a database with a SQL Server database varbinary(max) column with attribute [FILESTREAM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109.aspx).

Carrierwave apparently stores files in a created storage location, but I would like to use the sql server as the storage location seeing that it creates one on its own when specifying filestream. This cuts down on a lot of fetching file paths which is why I've chosen this storage method. Keep in mind SQL server creates a pointer to the actual binary when an object is saved in the varbinary(max) column.

Essentially, how can I make carrier store a file in a database varbinary(max) column?

Please help and thanks for sharing knowledge.